# Regex - Match string before a character

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

using regex in Sublime Text. I'd like to find all characters before a tab (\t). The string:

```
Peace love and happiness    2
```

Would return:

```
Peace love and happiness
```

I'm essentially doing this to nuke the first column in a tab-seperated document (.tsv). There is probably a better way to delete tab-seperated columns in Sublime Text, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Can you use sed? `sed "s/\([^\t]*\)\t/\1/g"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if Sublime has any particularly special regex rules, but it should be:

```
(.*)(?:\t)
```

Comment: Works in Sublime. Thank you!